# Why does chacha20 not use bitwise not?

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, chacha, arx

Right now **chacha20** and **blake** use constants in order to eliminate fixpoints. As far as I know however inserting a `bitwise not` every $n$ rounds should eliminate this issue without using constants (and as a bonus chacha20 would be a $\{0, 1\}^{512} \to \{0, 1\}^{512}$ function rather than a $\{0, 1\}^{384} \to \{0, 1\}^{512}$ as it currently is).

My questions are:

1. Why did Bernstein went with constants rather than bitwise not?
2. Would use bitwise not once every two rounds, for example, cause some kind of issue that I am not aware of?

Comment: using a bitwise not is the same as adding a constant of 1

Comment: @RichieFrame I am aware of that.

Comment: which cipher uses bit wise not for eliminating fixed points ? have you seen a particular cipher?

Comment: @hardyrama Xoodoo-p and Keccak-p, although these are not ARX, unlike Chacha20.

Comment: @8321992485 keccak uses a LFSR to generate constants, and im pretty sure it does not use NOT

Comment: @RichieFrame As per https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf at 2.3.5 the constants are there to protect against sliding attacks (rather than fixpoints). NOT is used in the step χ of the permutation which you can see in https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html

Comment: Seriously, ask Bernstein. Be nice, formal and don't necessarily expect an answer, he's pretty busy.

Comment: If the algorithm uses a “bitwise NOT” every $n$ rounds (instead of using separate constants for each round), wouldn’t it be possible to consider $n$ consecutive rounds as one “super-round”? Then all super-rounds are identical, which might impact the cryptographic strength.